# Which algorithm works best for this publlic transportation graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding

i have following graph:

[image]

As you can see it is a directional graph with circles. The dotted routes are no real stations.

For example this route a -> bigRound would result in following path: a-b-c-d-e-f-g-e-h-d-b-a

Another example route a->h would result in two found paths: a-b-c-d-e-h and a-b-c-d-e-f-g-e-h (including the southRound)

Im struggling to find a fitting algorithm for this kind of graph. Can you make any suggestions?

**To clarify**: I search a algorithm that gives me all possible paths from a certain start point to a certain end point. In addition to that this graph represents one round trip. Throughout the day there can be more than one. How do i need to change the graph or is there another method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "find a fitting algorithm..." for a graph? If I had to take a guess, it looks like what you're trying to do is list out all paths from some node to another, where edges are not reused.

Comment: @wLui155 It depends. The graph that is shown above is a route with each node representing a real world station. This route can be used more than once throughout the day, so edges can be used more than once. With fitting algorithm i was refering to some famouse algorithms like Dijksta, A*, etc... I´m unexperienced about this topic, so any suggestions are welcome

Comment: The problem you are trying to solve is not clear. Do you want to find the smallest distance between two stations? Do you want to find all possible paths between any two stations?

Comment: @nonDucor I want all possible paths. That lead from a giving start point to a given end point

Comment: Edit your question to clarify what you want to do.  Do not bury important details in coments.  There are lots of posts about how to find all possible paths between nodes in a graph - basically you use a modified DFS.

Comment: `a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h` is not a valid path on that graph, there is no arrow from `g` to `h`. As such you are trying find all possible paths while avoiding traversing the same link twice rather than the usual "not visiting the same node twice".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm to find all paths is a modified depth first search

```
Start by putting the start vertex on top of a stack.
LOOP
IF stack empty, STOP
Take the top vertex of the stack and add it to the visited list and the current path
Add adjacent vertices which aren't in the visited list to the top of the stack.
If the destination has been reached
    Add current path to output
    Backtrack along path to vertex adjacent to vertex on top of stack, marking vertices as unvisited
```

Comment: That might be the solution. I still have one problem left. Lets asume i have two full round  trips in one day. How would i need to adapt your code. @ravenspoint

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'two full round trips'.  Your question asked for all the paths between two nodes.  Chooses one path to go from a to b.  To return, use the algorithm again to find the paths from b to a.  Select one for the return.  Repeat to do a second time.  I suppose you mean something different than this, but you will have to describe what it is.